# Separation of Storage & Compute in Snowflake

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud

One of the key features in Snowflake is the separation of storage and compute.

While I do understand what it means, I realized that I actually don't really grasp what is so special about this. More specifically, I don't see what it means not to have it, at least in the context of cloud databases.

For instance, I read that Redshift does not provide that. What does that imply? What can a software like Redshift not do without it (or does less well) that Snowflake can?

> Note: I do not mean to discuss the merits of various solutions, but only their objective differences with regards to one specific feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main takeaway of Snowflake's decoupling of storage and compute is the scalability. Meaning that you can any amount of users can access the same data without the compute being underutilized in non peak hours. From [here](https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Snowflake_Inside_the_Elastic_Data_Warehouse_WP.pdf)

> Cloud infrastructure uniquely enables full elasticity
> because resources can be added and discarded at any time. That makes
> it possible to have exactly the resources you need for all users and
> workloads, but only with an architecture designed to take full
> advantage of the cloud. Snowflake’s separation of storage, compute,
> and system services makes it possible to dynamically modify the
> configuration of the system. Resources can be sized and scaled
> independently and transparently, on-the-fly. This makes it possible
> for Snowflake to deliver full elasticity across multiple dimensions:
>
> **Data**: The amount of data stored can be increased or decreased at any time. Unlike shared-nothing architectures where the ratio of
> storage to compute is fixed, the compute configuration is determined
> independently of the volume of data in the system. This architecture
> also makes it possible to store data at a very low cost because no
> compute resources are required to store data in the database.
>
> **Compute**: The compute resources being used for query processing can also be
> scaled up or down at any time as the intensity of the workload on the
> system changes. Because storage and compute are decoupled, and the
> data is dynamically distributed, changing compute resources does not
> require reshuffling the data. Compute resources can be changed
> on-the-fly, without disruption.

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling storage and compute allows for independent scaling of each.  This can be very powerful as it allows for right-sizing of each and the flexibility to modulate compute easily as workloads change.

There is a downside to this.  The hardware also needs to be decoupled in order to enable this capability which adds cost and created data movement bottlenecks.  To mitigate these bottlenecks the software implements advanced caching and other techniques which work fairly well in most cases but these lead to new performance trade-offs and some additional costs.  It's a classic "what the costs and benefits of flexibility?" situation and each are hard to quantify.

The choice between flexible and bespoke resources comes down to the customers needs.  If you have a large, fairly fixed workload then bespoke resources will deliver higher performance at a lower cost.  But if your workload is highly variable then flexibility will deliver lower costs.  There is no magic in the universe, decoupling has costs and benefits.

To clarify what you stated about Redshift it does offer a number of different options for fixed compute to storage ratios for provisioned clusters.  These provisioned cluster types can also address additional data stored in the cloud, Redshift Spectrum, that gives extendability of storage.  They also have concurrency scaling that allows for compute to automatically scale up as workload increases. Additionally, Redshift has a fully decoupled option, the RA3 type, that gives complete storage to compute flexibility.  So your comparison point is only valid if we talk about Redshift capabilities of 7 or 8 years ago which I did in my answer above.